# From auto-save script does not save form properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a script that looks for a user to be idle, and when they are for x amount of seconds, it executes a submission of the form the user was on(saving their data, and refreshing the page back to the existing form).  For some reason, it is refreshing the page, and NOT submitting the form, causing the form to lose all data in the process :P.  Is there something I am missing in the code?

Script Code :

```
<!-- Set auto save timeout in milliseconds -->
<script type="text/javascript">
attachEvent(window,'load',function(){
  var idleSeconds = 5;
  var idleTimer;
  function resetTimer(){
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    idleTimer = setTimeout(whenUserIdle,idleSeconds*1000);
  }
  attachEvent(document.body,'mousemove',resetTimer);
  attachEvent(document.body,'keydown',resetTimer);
  attachEvent(document.body,'click',resetTimer);

  resetTimer(); // Start the timer when the page loads
});

function whenUserIdle(){
        document.project.submit();
        window.location = location.href;
}

function attachEvent(obj,evt,fnc,useCapture){
  if (obj.addEventListener){
    obj.addEventListener(evt,fnc,!!useCapture);
    return true;
  } else if (obj.attachEvent){
    return obj.attachEvent("on"+evt,fnc);
  }
} 
</script>
```

Form Code :

```
<form name="project" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="invoice-form" method="post"  class="invoice-form" role="form" novalidate>
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off submitting your form asynchronously. A constantly refreshing site (even if it's only when I'm idle) seems annoying.

Comment: @MikeC do you have a link or something giving a tutorial on how to do that?  The refreshing will only happen once every 5-10min or so(whatever is most convenient).  I also implemented a page position script so that when it DOES refresh, it will automatically go to your place on the page(so you wont have to scroll back down)

Comment: There are tutorials *everywhere* about using AJAX. If you do a google search for "how to use ajax" you'll be drowning in a sea of tutorials.